# Problems with Float on core-data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios4, ipad

The following code largely inspired by some example I found on the net seems to work fine, with the core data entity called "Contact" and the property called "address" having an attribute String, in the xcdatamodel. It saves my data with no problem.
Now my question is : how do I need to modify this code ? In order to make it work after I change the attribute of the property "address" from String to Float in the xcdatamodel.

```
CoreDataTestOneAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newContact;
newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newContact setValue:address_InputField.text forKey:@"address"];
NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

To store a float in a Core Data float attribute, wrap it in a NSNumber object like this:

```
[newContact setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatValue] forKey:@"address"];
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I write the code for your "floatValue" ? The value of my float has been typed in by the user in the address_InputField which is a UITextField.

Comment: Read about NSNumberFormatter in the docs, also be sure to check your locales too (for it to parse correctly separators like , or .) the code should be like  NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 NSNumber *yourNumber = [numFormatter numberFromString:textField.text];

Comment: I have tried [newContact setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[address_InputField.text floatValue]] forKey:@"address"]; but it failed. Under the debugger it seems that the line : NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext]; fails. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Try deleting old model store. If you have one lying around that has the old object model (schema) then you may be running into trouble trying to open that store without migration policies in place. You might also want to do a clean rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but I think you will need to wrap that float in a NSNumber. numberWithFloat:

```
Creates and returns an NSNumber object containing a given value, treating it as a float.

+ (NSNumber *)numberWithFloat:(float)value
```