# Setting the value of a double attribute on NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am trying to implement a maps feature on my application. However to I would like the latitude and longitude be passed into the map from an object that is stored in core data. However I am having problem setting the initial value on the object when I start my application. I have tried 2 different ways so far and each and error I receive is "Sending 'double to a parameter of incompatible type 'id'. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
NSManagedObject *room = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Room" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    double myLatitude = -1.228087;
    double myLongitude = 52.764397;

    [room setValue:@"H001" forKey:@"code"];
    [room setValue:@"This is a description" forKey:@"roomDescription"];
    [room setValue:myLatitude forKey:@"longitude"];
    [room setValue:myLatitude forKey:@"latitude"];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` attributes need to be objects, but `double` is a primitive C type. The solution is to wrap the doubles in an `NSNumber`:

```
[room setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myLongitude] forKey:@"longitude"];
[room setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myLatitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was something along them lines but didn't know how to set it up to use the double.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your double as an NSNumber:

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble]
```

NSManagedObject setValue:forKey: requires an id for it's value. The double is a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5038587/74118) tells you how to store a float in Core Data. Here it is for a double

```
[room setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myLatitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
```