# Difficulty loading integer from Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an integer stored in my `core data` and set as type `integer 32`. I can read and write to `core data` fine and all is well with text and dates etc. But I seem to have difficulty with the integer values.

The entity is **Status** and I am trying to retrieve both the **lastMessageDate** and the **lastMessageID** fields. There is only ever going to be one record in this entity. The date is retrieved fine but the integer not.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Status"];
NSError *error = nil;
self.updateStatus = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSDate *lastSavedMessageDate = [[self.updateStatus objectAtIndex:0] lastMessageDate];
NSInteger lastSavedMessageID = [[self.updateStatus objectAtIndex:0] lastMessageID];
```

What is retrieved is not the actual number stored. I guess this is could be to do with pointers, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get the number that is actually stored.

An associated problem is when I am trying to save to this field. The date saves fine but including the integer save I get an error:

```
for (NSManagedObject *updatedRecord in [self updateStatus])
{
[updatedRecord setValue:now forKey:@"lastMessageDate"];
[updatedRecord setValue:newMessageID forKey:@"lastMessageID"];
}
NSError *errorUpdate;
[context save:&errorUpdate];
```

> Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'id' is disallowed
>   with ARC

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would use NSNumber http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886160/setting-the-value-of-a-double-attribute-on-nsmanagedobject basically the same for integer

Comment: lastMessageID will be returned as an NSNumber, try [[[self.updateStatus objectAtIndex:0] lastMessageID] integerValue];

Comment: NSNumber should fix your problem, and i think that NSInterger is an Interger 64, not 32 : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html

Comment: @JamesP - perfect ... did the trick thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated you need to use `NSNumber` the reason for this is that Core Data only deals in objects where integer is a primitive.  When you populate a number value of any form in a Core Data entity it must be a `NSNumber` which with the new auto boxing available is fairly trivial.

Converting a NSNumber to a primitive is as simple as calling the right method on the object, in this case it would be `-intValue`.